# Change value name in data frame

Tags: r

My data frame (mydf):

```
PL YEAR
a X2013
a X2012
a X2011
b X2013
b X2012
b X2011
```

How could we remove all the "X" in the YEAR column?

I tried without success :

```
mydf$YEAR <- as.character(mydf$YEAR)
mydf$YEAR[mydf$YEAR == "X"] <- NULL  # or just "" instead of NULL
```

Comment: good idea, I created a new column (year2) filled with substr(mydf$YEAR, 2, 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the unwanted `X` from the `YEAR` column.

```
> mydf
##   PL  YEAR
## 1  a X2013
## 2  a X2012
## 3  a X2011
## 4  b X2013
## 5  b X2012
## 6  b X2011
> mydf$YEAR <- gsub("X", "", mydf$YEAR)     ## or gsub("[^0-9]", "", mydf$YEAR)
> mydf
##   PL YEAR
## 1  a 2013
## 2  a 2012
## 3  a 2011
## 4  b 2013
## 5  b 2012
## 6  b 2011
```

As pointed out in the comments, it can also be done with `substring`

```
> mydf$YEAR <- substring(mydf$YEAR, 2, 5)   ## or substr(...) returns the same
```